# Chi square testing for sub-groups within a variable

Tags: chi-squared, gtsummary

New to R.  Using gtsummary to create contingency tables.  Created the one below using the following code:

```
  select(ethnicity,smoking_merge) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = ethnicity,
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
                     all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"),
    digits = all_continuous() ~ 1,
    type = all_categorical() ~ "categorical",
    missing_text = "Missing") %>%
    add_p())
```

| Smoking status | Group A | Group B | Group C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Smoker | 44 | 17 | 2182 |
| Ex-smoker | 54 | 5 | 4625 |
| Never smoked | 201 | 5 | 5724 |

I get one p value for this.

What I would like to do is determine a p value for each subgroup i.e. p value for smokers (when comparing gp A vs gp B vs gp C), ex-smokers and never smokers.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Thank you!

Comment: The `add_p()` is going to give you one p-value for variable in the table. To get p-values for each level, create dummy variables for each level of your variable and summarize each of the dummy variables with `tbl_summary() %>% add_p()`

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thanks for getting back to me. Forgive me for my ignorance but would you please be able to clarify what you mean by creating dummy variables for level? Thanks so much

Comment: Create 3 binary variables, one each for Smoking, Ex-smoker, and never smoker